# How can I find out what software has been updated on my system in macOS?

Tags: macos, updates

I have my macOS Sonoma (14.3) set to automatically update apps in the background.

This is great! But is there any way to see what apps have been updated in macOS and when?

Sometimes it would be nice to what is installed, and when, if there is a need to debug issues with an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking when updates have happened on macOS, is easy but definitely not obvious. This is what I had to do to find update information in macOS Sonoma (14.3):

1. From the Finder, hold down <kbd>Option</kbd>; it will change “About This Mac” to “System Information.” Click that.
2. Then scroll to “Software > Installations”
3. And from there you can see a list of items installed and you can sort by “Install Date.”

Or take the long way to it with these steps:

1. Go to “About This Mac.”
2. Then choose “More Info…”
3. And then scroll down to see “System Report…”
4. Then scroll to “Software > Installations”
5. And from there you can see a list of items installed and you can sort by “Install Date.”

Comment: You can skip steps 2 and 3 if you press the Option key at the start. "About this Mac" changes to "System Information".